# Sumproduct formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

i have two sheets raw Data and Summary. i need help in editing below formula which i am using in my VBA code. i am looking for sum of one particular id for multiple conditions. in summary unique ids and i already have this formula which is working fine

`=SUMPRODUCT(('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2)*('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457={"HAUD","AANZ","CSHK","HCNY","CHN1,CHN2","IN1","DBIN","CSJL","CTOK","BTK","K01","MYFM","MYPB","HNZD","BNZD","PKDB","HSBP","SCS","SCTW","SCT","SCT"})*('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF")*('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457))`

sum in "G" column sholud also include cells in D column which begins with "TW" or "K"

i tried this but its not working
`=SUMPRODUCT(('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2)*(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW"))*(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="K"))*('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457={"HAUD","AANZ","CSHK","HCNY","CHN1, CHN2","IN1","DBIN","CSJL","CTOK","BTK","K01","MYFM","MYPB","HNZD","BNZD","PKDB","HSBP","SCS","SCTW","SCT","SCT"})*('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF")*('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457)`

your assistance highly appreciated

below one is also tried it shows blank all "," are replaced with * still shows Blank

`=SUMPRODUCT('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457,--('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2),(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW")+(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,1)="K"),--ISNUMBER(MATCH('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,{"HAUD","AANZ","CSHK","HCNY","CHN1","CHN2","IN1","DBIN","CSJL","CTOK","BTK","K01","MYFM","MYPB","HNZD","BNZD","PKDB","HSBP","SCS","SCTW","SCT","SCT"},0)),--('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF"))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first formula should be more like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2)*('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457={"HAUD","AANZ","CSHK","HCNY","CHN1","CHN2","IN1","DBIN","CSJL","CTOK","BTK","K01","MYFM","MYPB","HNZD","BNZD","PKDB","HSBP","SCS","SCTW","SCT","SCT"})*('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF")*('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457)*((LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW")+(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,1)="K")))
```

There was no quotes in `"CHN1,CHN2"` in both the first and the working formula that I added. I also changed

```
(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW"))*(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="K"))
```

to

```
((LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW")+(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,1)="K"))
```

The last one should work if you change the `,` in the array to `;` (to mean a vertical array):

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457,--('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2),(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW")+(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,1)="K"),--ISNUMBER(MATCH('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,{"HAUD";"AANZ";"CSHK";"HCNY";"CHN1";"CHN2";"IN1";"DBIN";"CSJL";"CTOK";"BTK";"K01";"MYFM";"MYPB";"HNZD";"BNZD";"PKDB";"HSBP";"SCS";"SCTW";"SCT";"SCT"},0)),--('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF"))
```

Comment: no.. it still shows blank i would like to clarify that i have multiple conditions in D and F column under same id in A column

Comment: no.. it still shows blank i would like to clarify that i have multiple conditions in D and F column under same id in A column like this cell A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 =A100; D2,D3 = K11; D4,D5=HAUD; D6,D7 = TW; cells F2,F3,F4=BLF; F6,F7=MRG

Comment: @user3494415 It's hard to understand your problem exactly. Is it possible for you to put a sample workbook on [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/) and link me to it?

Comment: thnx Jerry i found the answer with sum research
=SUMPRODUCT('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$3457,--('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$3457=A2),(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,2)="TW")+(LEFT('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,1)="K")+(--ISNUMBER(MATCH('Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$3457,{"HAUD","AANZ","CSHK","HCNY","CHN1","CHN2","IN1","DBIN","CSJL","CTOK","BTK","K01","MYFM","MYPB","HNZD","BNZD","PKDB","HSBP","SCS","SCTW","SCT","SCT"},0))),--('Raw Data'!$F$2:$F$3457="BLF"))